# How to create custom shortcut in VSC, for "border: size, color, style"

Tags: html, css

I'm learning web development and I just started learning flexbox. I've noticed it's much easier to learn flexbox when I'm putting borders around every object so I can see what exactly am I changing. I have found it a bit clumsy to write the full code for "border: color, size, style" every time and I would like to create a custom shortcut so that VSC will be able to generate this simple line of code for me. ideally with a random color every time but if not then let's say black color. so the end result should be something like this:

writing: "brdr" (or anything else or even just ctrl+random keys, doesn't matter) and pressing enter would auto-fill the line:
`border: 1px solid black;`. or even better, a random color every time.

I guess I can add this as a macro shortcut but preferably there is an option for this in VSC so I can share it with my class.

thanks, everyone and sorry if the question is not formatted correctly, still new here.

took a look at "add snippet" but it was too confusing for a beginner and I didn't want to mess anything up

Comment: This link might help you: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Comment: Or just try * {border: 1px solid black;} in your CSS :)

Comment: thank you raph, that helped and i managed to create a costum snippet using this code: ```"Border Shortcut": {
  "prefix": "brdr",
  "body": "border: 1px solid black;",
  "description": "Shortcut to a border"
 } ```. only remaining question is how to make the color random every time and not static.. if its even possible.